# Using Map() in a Recursive Function in R

Tags: r, loops, dictionary, recursion, tidyverse

Here is my BOM with a data structure approach:

```
    dput(df2)
structure(list(product_id = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", 
"P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P2"), item_id = c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", 
"i8", "i9", "i10", "i11", "i12", "i13", "i14", "i15", "i16", 
"i17", "i18"), sup_item_id = c("i6", "i6", "i6", "i6", "i8", 
"i8", "i9", "i9", NA, "i15", "i15", "i15", "i15", "i17", "i17", 
"i18", "i18", NA), quantity = c(2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1), price = c(2, 5, 3, 7, 10, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
2, 5, 3, 7, 20, 0, 2, 0, 0), itemtype = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", 
"C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

To define the item levels (from top to bottom) Here is the recursive function with a loop inside:

```
change_df <- function(df, changed = TRUE, idx = which(df$production_level == 1)) {
  
  for (i in idx) {
    descendants <- which(df$sup_item_id == df$item_id[i])
    
    if (length(descendants) > 0) {
      new_levels <- df$production_level[i] + 1
      
      if (any(df$production_level[descendants] < new_levels)) {
        df$production_level[descendants] <- new_levels
        df <- change_df(df, idx = idx)
      }
      
    }
  }
  return(df)
}
```

I then call it this way:

```
 df2 %>%
  arrange(product_id, item_id) %>%
  mutate(production_level = ifelse(is.na(sup_item_id), 0, 1)) %>% 
  change_df(df2)
```

This is the output of my code:

```
product_id item_id sup_item_id quantity price itemtype production_level
1          P1      i1          i6        2     2        A          3
2          P1      i2          i6        2     5        A          3
3          P1      i3          i6        5     3        A          3
4          P1      i4          i6        1     7        A          3
5          P1      i5          i8        1    10        A          2
6          P1      i6          i8        2     0        B          2
7          P1      i7          i9        4     4        A          1
8          P1      i8          i9        1     0        B          1
9          P1      i9        <NA>        1     0        C          0
10         P2     i10         i15        2     2        A          3
11         P2     i11         i15        2     5        A          3
12         P2     i12         i15        5     3        A          3
13         P2     i13         i15        1     7        A          3
14         P2     i14         i17        1    20        A          2
15         P2     i15         i17        2     0        B          2
16         P2     i16         i18        4     2        A          1
17         P2     i17         i18        1     0        B          1
18         P2     i18        <NA>        1     0        C          0
```

I dont want to change the output. Now I want to use map() function in R instead of the loop to make my code more compact. I also wonder if the idx approach is good or would something else work better. If you have any suggestions, please share!

Comment: Why would you pass df2 into the change function twice? if `%>% change_df(., df2)` is your final call, but the second parameter is a logical one.

Comment: You are right it's unnecessary to pass it twice, but when I tried to remove it the loop didn't stop running I don't know why. Any suggestion?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this recursion? It is not clear as to what you need.  Can you elaborate? Maybe there is a vectorized version

Comment: How can we advise you on how to improve your code if you don't tell us what your purpose is? At the very least, we need to see the output you expect from the input you provide, together with a description of the logic of your algorithm.

Comment: Yes, what I was trying to do is to find the production levels for each product based on the tree structure of item_id and sup_item_id (each item id is used in a specific production level from level max to level 0 given that A are the raw components, B are the sub-components and C are the finished products). Now if there is any tidy way to do it without including updating the values based on raw indices update it will be good! I know that map() can replace a loop to make the code more compact that was want I wanted

Comment: I updated my post with the output of my code and I don't want to change the output. It should remain the same but I need the code to be more compact and flexible and I want to try using map() instead of the for loop I am using.

Comment: Sounds like a graph problem. Can we group by product_id or is there a chance that different products share the same item_ids / sup_item_ids?

Comment: yes some item_ids can be shared between products

Answer (score 3):

If you would consider using *tidygraph* / *igraph* instead, try if this works and scales on your actual data.

`item_id` and `sup_item_id` are used as from / to edge columns for creating *tidygraph* object. There's a warning about "NA" string, as tidygraph added a node named "NA", filtering deals with that.

`igraph` provides [eccentricity measure](https://igraph.org/r/html/latest/eccentricity.html),

> The eccentricity of a vertex is its shortest path distance from the farthest other node in the graph.

and this should be precisely what you are after, though please test with corner cases like shared `item_id`s and such.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidygraph)

# to_from_df, a 2-column data.frame for igraph edges
# returns node eccentricity measure vector
node_level <- function(from_to_df){
  as_tbl_graph(from_to_df) %>% 
    activate(nodes)  %>% 
    filter(name != "NA") %>% 
    mutate(eccentricity = node_eccentricity()) %>% 
    pull(eccentricity)
}

df %>% mutate(production_level = node_level(pick(item_id, sup_item_id)))

#> Warning: There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
#> ℹ In argument: `production_level = node_level(pick(item_id, sup_item_id))`.
#> Caused by warning in `graph_from_data_frame()`:
#> ! In `d' `NA' elements were replaced with string "NA"
#>    product_id item_id sup_item_id quantity price itemtype production_level
#> 1          P1      i1          i6        2     2        A                3
#> 2          P1      i2          i6        2     5        A                3
#> 3          P1      i3          i6        5     3        A                3
#> 4          P1      i4          i6        1     7        A                3
#> 5          P1      i5          i8        1    10        A                2
#> 6          P1      i6          i8        2     0        B                2
#> 7          P1      i7          i9        4     4        A                1
#> 8          P1      i8          i9        1     0        B                1
#> 9          P1      i9        <NA>        1     0        C                0
#> 10         P2     i10         i15        2     2        A                3
#> 11         P2     i11         i15        2     5        A                3
#> 12         P2     i12         i15        5     3        A                3
#> 13         P2     i13         i15        1     7        A                3
#> 14         P2     i14         i17        1    20        A                2
#> 15         P2     i15         i17        2     0        B                2
#> 16         P2     i16         i18        4     2        A                1
#> 17         P2     i17         i18        1     0        B                1
#> 18         P2     i18        <NA>        1     0        C                0
```

Example data:

```r
df <- structure(list(product_id = c(
  "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1",
  "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2",
  "P2"
), item_id = c(
  "i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7",
  "i8", "i9", "i10", "i11", "i12", "i13", "i14", "i15", "i16",
  "i17", "i18"
), sup_item_id = c(
  "i6", "i6", "i6", "i6", "i8",
  "i8", "i9", "i9", NA, "i15", "i15", "i15", "i15", "i17", "i17",
  "i18", "i18", NA
), quantity = c(
  2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2,
  2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1
), price = c(
  2, 5, 3, 7, 10, 0, 4, 0, 0,
  2, 5, 3, 7, 20, 0, 2, 0, 0
), itemtype = c(
  "A", "A", "A", "A",
  "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B",
  "C"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this solution is working perfectly, I just mutated df2 replacing NA with 0 and no error was produced. However, I wanted to stick to tidyverse package and use only map reducing to compact my code.